# iOS and Android Cross-Platform Game Development

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, cocos2d-x

My friend and I are starting a company focusing on app development for mobile devices. He is the Android guy, so he is skilled in Java, and I am the iOS guy, knowing Objective-C. We are developing our first game and we are wondering, what is the best way to maintain a consistent experience across devices? We have considered using Cocos2D-x, but neither of us have much experience with C++. Would it be worth it to try Cocos2D-x, or will it be possible to write native apps for both platforms and maintain the same user experience?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should develop the game on one platform and then port to the other.  Writing the same game on 2 platforms at the same time sounds like a nightmare.  iOS and Android come with their own sets of problems.  Cocos2d-x sounds promising for multiplatform development but it all depends on the type of game you are going for.
If you are going to do native for each platform, whichever of you guys is the stronger programmer I would work on that platform first. Solve the game problems and then port.

Answer (score 0):

As a cross-platform development solution for iOS and Android development consider [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).

It would reduce the effort of having to port the whole code from one platform to the other, by enabling to share the none visual logic between iOS and Android, while having access to the look and feel of native GUI widgets. One might get the native look, but it's another story to get the feel.

Having successfully tested it, the major differentiator about Xamarin approach to cross-platform is that the logic can be shared among iOS and Android, while the GUI can be build using native GUI tools.

PS I'm not working for Xamarin or any how related to Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Thats really give me a motivation to develop mobile apps, as am also want to develop my own mobile apps. but as i seen in comments above which is good to know that we should focus on one platform to develop first and to do a good starting.